# Loading temporary layer in processing PyQgis 3.4

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have been working on processing script in PyQgis 3.4 and i have serious issues with loading temporary layers to project after processing. Since following code works perfectly fine:

```
entimport processing
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
    print(feature['FIELD_LEN'])
    field_len=feature['FIELD_LEN']
    spacing=feature['SPACING']
    spacing_corr = (field_len/spacing) + 1
    processed_lyr = processing.run('qgis:pointsalonglines', {"INPUT": layer, "DISTANCE": spacing_corr, "START_OFFSET":0, "END_OFFSET":0, "OUTPUT":'d:/test.shp'})
```

I wanted for output to be temporary layer, so I switched "OUTPUT:"

```
processed_lyr = processing.run('qgis:pointsalonglines', {"INPUT": layer, "DISTANCE": spacing_corr, "START_OFFSET":0, "END_OFFSET":0, "OUTPUT":'memory:'})
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(processed_lyr["OUTPUT"])
```

but  I have no idea how to acess it since it produces error

```
TypeError: QgsProject.addMapLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
```

What should be used instead of .addMapLayers?

Comment: Try with addMapLayer() :)

Comment: Such a stupid mistake, thank you, it helped!